# Datetime Conversion with ValueError

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with columns containing start and stop times in this format: `2016-01-01 00:00:00`

I would like to convert these times to datetime objects so that I can subtract one from the other to compute total duration. I'm using the following:

```
import datetime

df = df['start_time'] = 
df['start_time'].apply(lambda x:datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y/%m/%d/%T %I:%M:%S %p'))
```

However, I have the following ValueError:

`ValueError: 'T' is a bad directive in format '%Y/%m/%d/%T %I:%M:%S %p'`

Comment: It seems your resource is in `c`, not in `python`

Comment: @jezrael You are right. I too was confused with that.

Comment: Thanks; edited to remove the incorrect link to avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would convert the column into [datetime64](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) dtype. Then you could process whatever you need using that column.

```
df['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Also if you want to avoid explicitly specifying datetime format you can use the following:

```
df['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpliest is use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'])
```